# Manipulate xticks, need every second xtick to just be the decimal and smaller font

Tags: python, matplotlib

So, as a beginner python user, I can not even BEGIN to work out how to do this. It is very difficult to search for help online, as it just turns up lots of junk results.

But basically I have a plot where the xticks look like:
`14.0, 14.5, 15.0, 15.5, 16.0, 16.5, ... etc` and I would like to have it instead looking like
`14, .5, 15, .5, 16, .5, ...`

That is, every 'whole number' displays as an integer, and every .5 increment is listed only as .5 (or 0.5 if that is too tough) and has a smaller font.

I hope this is as challenging as my mind is making it out to be!

**Whoever answers this shall be forever known as the greatest py-zard of the decade!**

oh a little more info: my xmin and xmax are non integer so I am using
`xticks(np.arange(np.ceil(xmin),np.ceil(xmax),0.5))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way to do this is to use `FuncFormatter`

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

def alternate_formatter(x, ind):
    rm = np.mod(x, 1)
    if np.abs(rm) < .1:
        return '{:d}'.format(int(x))
    return '{:.1f}'.format(rm)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(.5))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(alternate_formatter))

ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
```

An even better way (and an easy way to get the font size change) is to use minor ticks as well:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

def minor_formatter(x, ind):
    # only format if we don't overlap with a major tick
    if np.mod(x, 1) < .1:
        return ''
    return '{:.1f}'.format(np.mod(x, 1))

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(.5))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(FuncFormatter(minor_formatter))
# label size sets the font size, pad sets the distance from the spine
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(which='minor', labelsize=8, pad=8)


ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
```

[image]

I consider directly using `xticks` to be dangerous, it can in inadvertently de-couple your data from your axes labels.

Comment: YOU! oh you!! ... I forgot to un-accept the other answer. It was pretty messy I ended up just scrapping the idea. You are right, it definately did de-couple my data. This is amazing, thank you! :D

Answer (score -1):

You can create the xticks, e.g., as follows:

```
xtks = []
for x in np.arange(np.ceil(xmin), np.ceil(xmax)):
    xtks.append(str(int(x)))
    xtks.append(".5")
```

Then set the ticks with, e.g.:

```
ax = pyplot.figure().add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot( ... your data ... )
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(np.ceil(xmin), np.ceil(xmax), 0.5))
ax.set_xticklabels(xtks)
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: This is a good start :) ... it does however get a `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` with the `xticks(xticks)` ... changing this double-naming of `xticks` I still get a `TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type`

Comment: Just needs to be edited to have your `xticks = []` named something else e.g. `xtks = []` and instead of  `xticks(xtks)` need to use `set_xticklabels(xtks)`

Comment: Okay, the problem with this is that is labels e.g. 14 = .5 15=15 16=.5 17=16, 18=.5 19=16

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's not the xticks but the xticklabels that you need to set. And the second problem that you mention is because you need first to set the xticks as well in order to make sure that the labels and the ticks are matched. I edited the answer.

Comment: You sir, are a wizard. Many thanks... now to make the font smaller on  the appended .5 (I have some ideas, me thinks :D)